# Приложение для проектирования схемы БД

Tags: база-данных, поиск-программ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, похожее приложение для проектирования схемы БД.

1. Плавные стрелки (а не сгибающиеся только под прямым углом)
2. Стрелка идет от поля к полю (а не просто от таблицы к таблице)
3. Желательно минималистичный интерфейс (свойста поля, название, тип)

Данное не устраивает тем, что это веб-приложение (www.dbdesigner.net).
Нужен десктоп.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если для MySQL, то попробуйте [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Не совсем то, что вам нужно, но очень удобно

Comment: Пробовал, не подходит